# How do I use warpPerspective correctly?

Tags: c++, opencv

Here are the files [The output with the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aAEe.jpg) and here is the image used in the code;  [The actual card used in the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS8e8.jpg) 
. The blue positions are from paint. Output is the output from the code.
I have attached the image I am talking about. I want to get the perspective transformation so I can get the card in its canonical form. It does not work and I get a bad output.

This is my code. The points I got from point and they are correct (checked with the function circle() )

```
void main(){
cv::Mat begin = cv::imread("\cards.jpg");
cv::Mat output;
cv::Point2f Poly2[4] = {
              cv::Point2f(222,93),
              cv::Point2f(430,134),
              cv::Point2f(368,426),   //points I got from looking in paint.
              cv::Point2f(162,378),

};

cv::Point2f Points[4] = {
              cv::Point2f(0,0),
              cv::Point2f(300,0),
              cv::Point2f(0,600),       //The picture I want to transform to. 
              cv::Point2f(600,300),

};

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    cv::circle(begin, cv::Point2d(Poly2[i].x, Poly2[i].y), 2, cv::Scalar(244, 233, 44), 3, 8, 0);
}

cv::Mat Matrix = cv::getPerspectiveTransform( Points,Poly2);

cv::warpPerspective(begin, output, Matrix, cv::Size(300, 600));

cv::imshow("begin", begin);
cv::imshow("Output", output);
cv::waitKey(0);
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first mistake is that the points you took by using paint ( you may also use opencv `imshow` to do that ) is not in the correct order. They should be accordingly: `left-up` , `right-up` , `left-down` and `right-down`.

Your second and actual mistake is about the order of [getPerspectiveTransform](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga20f62aa3235d869c9956436c870893ae). You should first source then the desired(destination). If you correct these 2 mistakes you ll get the output like:

[image]

And the code:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{

    cv::Mat begin = cv::imread("/home/code/Documents/photos/cards.jpg");
    cv::Mat output;
    cv::Point2f Poly2[4] = {
                  cv::Point2f(222,93),
                  cv::Point2f(430,134),
                  cv::Point2f(162,378),
                  cv::Point2f(368,426),   //points I got from looking in paint.


    };

    cv::Point2f Points[4] = {
                  cv::Point2f(0,0),
                  cv::Point2f(300,0),
                  cv::Point2f(0,300),       //The picture I want to transform to.
                  cv::Point2f(300,300),

    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cv::circle(begin, cv::Point2d(Poly2[i].x, Poly2[i].y), 2, cv::Scalar(244, 233, 44), 3, 8, 0);
    }

    cv::Mat Matrix = cv::getPerspectiveTransform( Poly2,Points);

    cv::warpPerspective(begin, output, Matrix, cv::Size(300, 300));

    cv::imshow("begin", begin);
    cv::imshow("Output", output);
    cv::waitKey(0);


    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for clearly explained question

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are incorrectly calculating the destination coordinates for the transformation.

```
cv::Point2f Poly2[4] = {
              cv::Point2f(222,93),
              cv::Point2f(430,134),
              cv::Point2f(368,426),   //points I got from looking in paint.
              cv::Point2f(162,378),

};

double imWidth = cv::norm(Poly2[1]-Poly2[0]);
double imHeight = cv::norm(Poly2[2]-Poly2[1]);

// Destination points have to be in the same order as input points
cv::Point2f Points[4] = {
              cv::Point2f(0,0),
              cv::Point2f(imWidth-1, 0),
              cv::Point2f(imWidth-1, imHeight-1),       //The picture I want to transform to. 
              cv::Point2f(0, imHeight-1),

};

cv::Mat Matrix = cv::getPerspectiveTransform( Points,Poly2);
cv::warpPerspective(begin, output, Matrix, cv::Size(imWidth, imHeight));
```